# c# String.Format not adding a ' in the Numbers

Tags: c#

i have a small problem.. i cant solve the problem... 
I need format the numbers i get from DownloadString...
Just adding a ' in the numbers..

This work -  adds a ' in 12'000  ->

```
string a = string.Format("{0:#,###0}", 12000);
Console.WriteLine(a);
```

This not work - result still 13067->

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:#,###0}", item.price_usd));
```

Full code//

```
namespace ConsoleApp3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string json = new WebClient().DownloadString("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/");
            List<Item> items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>(json);

            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:C}", item.price_usd));

                string a = string.Format("{0:#,###0}", 12000);
                Console.WriteLine(a);
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
        public class Item
        {
            public string price_usd { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `12000` is a number. `"13094.3"` is not.  You might want to show the item class.  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON returned from https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/bitcoin/ has the `item.price_usd` as a string, not a number.

Change the definition of your item class to have the `price_usd` property as a decimal, not a string:

```
public class Item
{
    ...
    public decimal price_usd { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

As pointed out by David, there's no need to parse anything if your Item class has the correct types, as the deserializer will parse everything for you.

Comment: No need to parse anything, just change the `Item` class definition to be decimal instead of string in th first place.

Comment: Thx for the Information @DavidG and Erresen that i can use decimal in the class Item...

Answer (score -1):

Your

```
price_usd
```

is a string, so format does not know how to handle it. You could convert it to a number like so:

```
double.Parse(item.price_usd)
```

Comment: No need to parse anything, just change the `Item` class definition to be decimal instead of string in th first place. Also, never use `double` for currency types.

Comment: @DavidG darn - I missed it since it is so abbreviated... problem solved or [SOLVED] as they say elsewhere